# Using libcurl from NuGet in C++ (VS2013)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, libcurl

First timer here, so I may need a *bit* of handholding.

I've been trying to just used the simple libcurl examples but am tripping up when compiling.
I'm trying to use NuGet and followed what I read in [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20171165/getting-libcurl-to-work-with-visual-studio-2013/20339327#20339327)

In Project Properties I've linked *Additional Library Directories* to the folder with libcurl.dll in, and in *Linker->Input* I've the .lib's listed there in that previous answer.
When I try and run it, it gives an error about missing .libs.

`1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libeay32.lib'`
I guess that's not too surprising because the .lib's aren't actually in the folder. When removing references to the .lib's except for libcurl.lib because that is there, I get this error.

```
1>Source.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__curl_easy_init referenced in function _main
1>Source.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__curl_easy_setopt referenced in function _main
1>Source.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__curl_easy_perform referenced in function _main
1>Source.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__curl_easy_cleanup referenced in function _main
```

Comment: Thanks to what ruvenb pointed out, I've added those .libs but still get the errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The OpenSSL NuGet package is currently dated June 12, 2013. The targets files for both `openssl.1.0.1.24` and `openssl.redist.1.0.1.24` contain the following condition:

```
$(PlatformToolset.ToLower().IndexOf('v110')) &gt; -1
```

These preclude compilation and linking because VS2013 sets `PlatformToolset = v120` by default. The targets will have to be updated for `v120` (and for `CTP_Nov2013`).

More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21649610/if-using-visual-c-compiler-november-2013-ctp-do-all-dependencies-also-need-to) on compatibility between RTM and CTP compilers.

Comment: I'm having this issue too - how do you override this (you mention 'targets will have to be updated')

Comment: This can be done between compatible compilers (such as v120 and CPT_Nov2013) but not between v110 and v120/CPT_Nov2013. I ended up building OpenSSL and publishing my NuGet packages. See https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=evoskuil But I dropped cURL altogether.

Answer (score -1):

These are OpenSSL functions, which are used by curl. Strange that a package management system like nuget doesn't have automatic dependency tracking. In any case, installing OpenSSL in the same way you installed curl should resolve your issue.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out to me. NuGet downloads the other packages as well, so I had to add them also in project properties. That said, still have the same error.