# If using Visual C++ Compiler November 2013 CTP, do all dependencies also need to be compiled with it?

Tags: c#, c++, opencv, visual-studio-2013

I am writing a little interop with c# and c++ with a c++/cli project and just wanted to know if I compile my c++/cli project with Visual C++ Compiler November 2013 CTP, will my opencv dependencies projects that I have compiled with the normal v120 platform compiler work?

I dont want to install the november 2013 CTP if it means I have to make all dependencies work also. But if I can simply use my already compiled .lib / .dll files I will give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The November 2013 CTP just includes updates for the compiler, not the libraries so I would assume there would be no dependency issues.

http://herbsutter.com/2013/11/18/visual-c-compiler-november-2013-ctp/

"@Sometime: This is a compiler-only CTP to give a preview of new compiler features, it does not include library updates. Of course, when these features hit the full product in a future release, they’ll be complete including library support (among other library updates)."

Why not just test and see how it works? You can always check dependencies with DEPENDS.

Be careful though, CTPs like this are not really intended for production use.

Comment: okay, thanks :) Didnt test it to save time if someone already know the answer. Its a production solution, so didnt want to go over adding all this to remove it again :)