# VS2013 VC++ libcurl LNK2028 LNK2019 linking errors

Tags: visual-c++, curl, visual-studio-2013, static-libraries, libcurl

I'm trying to get Libcurl working in my VC++ project on VS2013 Community. I've been toiling with this for many hours, and I've tried essentially everything on Stack and Google about it, to no avail.

My most recent attempt was sparked by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20171165/getting-libcurl-to-work-with-visual-studio-2013/20339327#20339327) answer, that mentions libcurl as a Nuget package. This is good, because it comes with all of the .lib files required. I have however run into the same problem as [this fellow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21503738/using-libcurl-from-nuget-in-c-vs2013), in that I'm getting a linker error.

I'm importing the following libraries as 'Additional Dependencies' in the Project Configuration settings under Linker -> Input:

```
libcurl.lib;libeay32.lib;ssleay32.lib;Ws2_32.lib;libssh2.lib;zlib.lib;wldap32.lib;
```

Obviously, each one of these .lib files is in a different directory inside the nuget package folder inside the project folder, so under Linker -> General my 'Additional Library Directories' is set to:

```
"PATHTOPROJECT\packages\curl.7.30.0.2\build\native\lib\v110\x64\Release\static";
"PATHTOPROJECT\packages\zlib.1.2.8.1\build\native\lib\v110\Win32\Release\static\cdecl";
"PATHTOPROJECT\packages\openssl.1.0.1.21\build\native\lib\v110\x64\Release\static\cdecl";
"PATHTOPROJECT\packages\libssh2.1.4.3.1\build\native\lib\v110\x64\Release\static\cdecl";
```

I am trying to use static libraries, because I don't want to drag .dll's with my project executable if I can avoid it. It's also worth noting that my most recent attempt at using libcurl also includes SSL and whatnot, but I don't actually need those extras. Really, I just need a static libcurl library, but I can't find or compile one it seems.

In my code, I'm also using this include: `#include "curl/curl.h"`

I've also added the Additional Include directory correctly under 'Additional Include Directories' under C/C++ -> General:

```
PROJECTPATH\packages\curl.7.30.0.2\build\native\include
```

Now, this all compiles fine as long as I don't try and ***use*** curl in the project code.

So, the errors when I do try and use curl in the code:

```
CURL *curl;
curl = curl_easy_init();
```

That piece of code generates these errors:

```
1>Main.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A000453) "extern "C" void * __cdecl curl_easy_init(void)" (?curl_easy_init@@$$J0YAPAXXZ) referenced in function "private: class System::String ^ __clrcall Project::Main::CurlRequest(class System::String ^,class System::String ^,class System::String ^,class System::String ^)" (?CurlRequest@Main@Project@@$$FA$AAMP$AAVString@System@@P$AAV34@000@Z)
1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "extern "C" void * __cdecl curl_easy_init(void)" (?curl_easy_init@@$$J0YAPAXXZ) referenced in function "private: class System::String ^ __clrcall Project::Main::CurlRequest(class System::String ^,class System::String ^,class System::String ^,class System::String ^)" (?CurlRequest@Main@Project@@$$FA$AAMP$AAVString@System@@P$AAV34@000@Z)
```

There is of course more to my curl using code, but that bare minimum shows the basics of the linking error. What can I do to fix this? As I mentioned before I've tried a whole range of solutions, some of which I'll list below:

Many answers to the questions regarding problems using libcurl in VS projects mention downloading libcurl from http://curl.haxx.se/latest.cgi?curl=win32-devel-msvc, but that link doesn't work as of now, so I can't use it.

More answers say to just compile libcurl from source. The source comes with .vcproj files, none of which compile for me without hundreds of errors, so that's out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

[This Github project](https://github.com/blackrosezy/build-libcurl-windows) is a .bat file that downloads the libcurl source, compiles it, and makes the libraries (both static and dynamic). Importing the static library created by this (libcurl_a.lib) and using it in my project along with the include directory has worked.

I'll leave this question with an unaccepted answer in case someone can provide other helpful steps that would have fixed the problem I had in using the nuget package installation.

Finally.