# How Do I Get Libcurl To Work Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, cmake, libcurl, nmake

I've been trying to figure out how to install Libcurl on my VS2013 because I want to make a web bot. I downloaded the most recent **source** version of curl which is currently 7.41.0

I'm also wondering how to install the source libraries that were recommended as well(OpenSSL 1.0.2, libSSH2 1.4.3, and zlib 1.2.8). I do not yet know what exact libraries I will need for  my program, so maybe even a quick overview or a brief summary of what they do and why I (might) need them?

I prefer using the library statically, but dll is fine... as long as it works.

edit:

I have successfully used the Makefile by typing in

```
nmake /f Makefile.vc mode=static
```

Suggested by Marian Munteanu
for curl but now I do not know how to add the library to my project. I cannot include my header file

```
#include <curl/curl.h>
```

Also what else will I have to do to add OpenSSL, libSSH2, and zlib to my project?

Comment: nmake /f Makefile.vc mode=static

Comment: Have you tried https://quantcorner.wordpress.com/2012/04/08/using-libcurl-with-visual-c-2010/ ? Maybe this will help you further http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20171165/getting-libcurl-to-work-with-visual-studio-2013

Comment: Thank you Marian Munteanu the Makefile ran without error this time. I guess my question now is how do I add curl to my project? Also, how do I add the other libraries as well? usr1234567 I did try those methods and could not get it to function properly.