# How to use libcurl in a C++ project in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, curl, visual-studio-2013, libcurl

I've been trying to get curl linked to my project in Visual Studio 2013 and C++, however all tutorials online reference files that are not available anywhere in the archives you can download from their website. What I did was I went to http://curl.haxx.se/latest.cgi?curl=win32-ssl-devel-msvc and downloaded the package. All tutorials reference either a lib/Debug folder or some .dll or .lib files which just simply aren't there. The documentation on their website is from 2002, so that won't help either.

Could anyone explain which version I need to download and what I need to reference in my project properties and where? Thanks!

Comment: The link you provided lets you select from several packages. Which one did you download?

Comment: You should read this: [Getting LibCurl to work with Visual Studio 2013](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20171165/getting-libcurl-to-work-with-visual-studio-2013)

Comment: @molbdnilo The generic source (7.41.0)

Comment: @thinkerou I did, and they refer to the file curllib.dll which is not in any of the packages I downloaded

Answer (score 0):

Ok fixed it, had to build the libcurl.lib file from source. Changed build type to LIB Release and it worked! Thanks.

Comment: Can you post your example with images if you want ? or people will never vote you