# cURL with Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, curl, visual-studio-2013, nuget, libcurl

So i have came along with cURL as a very nice library and working very fine in OSX. 
But on windows now i have got big troubles with getting ready with this library. I googled now for about 2 days and tried over a dozen (in detail) different ways to get this ready. Without any success at all.

Here are some ways I basically tried:

1. **The direct Download**: The problem here already starts with the right download. The official download page is pretty confusing, so i considered this "cURL Download Wizard" > "libcurl development" which gives me a version, that i should be able to include into any project. But how exactly to include it? In ANY instructions out there it leads me to directories i dont even have. Almost always this "curllib.lib" is mentioned. I downloaded about 6 different versions on that downloadpage, in none of them there is this file. (See for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20171165/getting-libcurl-to-work-with-visual-studio-2013) instruction)
2. **Git + CMake**: As a solution on the aboves Link there is suggested to use git clone on this. I did all the instructions there and also get the Projects generated with just warnings. But here it says as well: 
   *After building install target, your will find bin/include/lib folders in C:\curl.vc12* 
    Well, i did not really get his point of "build install target", i just build the entire project map as it comes. Compiles fine (115 succeeded, 0 failed, 2 skipped). But now C:\curl.vc12 is not there. What do i have to pre-setup before compiling this?
3. **NuGet**: The idea comes from the link in point (1) again, a different solution with NuGet. 
   With `Successfully added 'curl 7.30.0.2' to test.` it also seemed nice, but compiling `simple.c` leads to a bunch of `unresolved external symbol` linker errors. But a solution is provided: 
   *Make sure the include directory and lib directory are specified under the Visual C++ directories in project properties.* 
   So in `Project > Properties > VC++ Properties > "Include Directories"` and 
    `Project > Properties > VC++ Properties > "Library Directories"` 
    as well as in `Project > C/C++ > General > "Additional Include Directories"` and in `Project > Linker > General > "Additional Library Directories"` I desperately added the \packages\ path from my project folder. 
   As mentioned in the instructions, I added `libcurl.lib;libeay32.lib;ssleay32.lib;Ws2_32.lib;libssh2.lib;zlib.lib;wldap32.lib;` to `Project > Linker > Input > "Additional Dependencies"`. 
   All that done, the `unresolved external symbol` errors are gone! Therefore I get just one error saying `cannot open file 'libcurl.lib'`. What can I do here?

I am pretty new to all that. But I am trying really hard now to get this finally to work. So what can I do? 
I work with Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition. The currently most recent version of cURL is `7.42.1`.
Any help is highly welcome!

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20171165/)?

Comment: Look into my question again. (The blue link)   (=

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Had problems myself, finally got it working now.
I downloaded *curl-7.42.1.zip* from the [official website](http://curl.haxx.se/download.html).
Within the archive you'll find the source code and winbuild/BUILD.WINDOWS.txt, which basically contains the instructions I followed. I'll assume that it has been unzipped to C:\curl-7.42.1.

Open the [Visual Studio command prompt](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229859%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) located at

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\Tools\Shortcuts

This automatically sets the environment variables needed to use Visual Studio tools like the compiler. Then move to the winbuild directory and call

> nmake /f Makefile.vc mode=dll

as described in the text file I mentioned above.

That will create the directory

> C:\curl-7.42.1\builds\libcurl-vc-x86-release-dll-ipv6-sspi-winssl

containing libcurl.dll, libcurl.lib and the necessary header files. Let's rename it to `C:\curl-7.42.1\builds\release` :'D

1. Then open your project.
2. Open your project's properties.
3. Make sure you choose *Release* as configuration (top left corner)!
4. Navigate to `VC++ Directories > Include directories` and add `C:\curl-7.42.1\builds\release\include`
5. Add `C:\curl-7.42.1\builds\release\lib` to `VC++ Directories > Library directories`.
6. Go to `Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies` and add `libcurl.lib`.
7. Finally copy `C:\curl-7.42.1\builds\release\bin\libcurl.dll` to your project folder.

That should do the trick! :D If you want to use cURL in debug mode, you can do almost the same, recompile using `nmake /f Makefile.vc mode=dll debug=yes`, go to your project's properties, add the newly created directory paths (changing libcurl.lib to libcurl_debug.lib) and you should be done.

Comment: With tears in my eyes and a cup of coffee in my hand I can go on, because you Sir made my day. (: Thank you very much!

Edit: Please change *Makefile.vs* to *Makefile.vc*

Comment: Nice to hear, you're welcome! :) Edited my post as you pointed out.

Comment: Also libcurl could be built for Windows using this build script: https://github.com/blackrosezy/build-libcurl-windows

Comment: Not work for me "about viewed 1217 times" 2 accepts ? definitely not works

Comment: @delive it does work, but there are some things that you need to be sure you're doing.  You need to make sure you're executing/compiling in 'Release' mode and not 'Debug' mode.  I was beating my head as well.  This gets you 95% of the way there, up to you to get the rest of the way.

Comment: I've spent two days on this, every states to build static. When I get back ,and this works. Many a man tear go unto you

Comment: Update: yisssss

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I downloaded the curl from https://github.com/curl/curl. you can actually compile it directly with Visual Studio 2013 (but be careful with parameters setting: x64 with release). The major difference is that it gives you libcurl_imp.lib. Then all you have to do is to set the environment variables as described above. Just want to mention, you will have to use libcurl_imp.lib rather than libcurl.lib in the additional dependencies (I suspect this change is because of the new version of curl).