# Preparing project for curl - Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio, curl

I did everything as it's written here: [cURL with Visual Studio 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30288415/curl-with-visual-studio-2013).
Visual showed such errors:

> unresolved external symbol __imp__curl_easy_setopt
>
> unresolved external symbol __imp__curl_easy_perform
>
> unresolved external symbol __imp__curl_easy_cleanup
>
> unresolved external symbol __imp__curl_easy_init`

I think it's problem with `libcurl.lib` but I don't have idea what I do wrong...
Include and library directories added as can been seen on this screenshot:

[image]

`libcurl.lib` also added...

[image]

Example code to run:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <curl/curl.h>


int main(void)
{
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://google.com");
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

        /* always cleanup */
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I spent a lot of time to search how can I add curl to my project, when there is real hope, once again had something doesn't work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see you forgot Step 3 from [cURL with Visual Studio 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30290407/5112690):

> Make sure you choose Release as configuration (top left corner)!

In your screenshot, you applied the settings on Debug configuration.

Comment: Works. I selected "release" option in build, forgot about configuration, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In file curl.h you can find this snippet

```
#ifdef CURL_STATICLIB
#  define CURL_EXTERN
#elif defined(WIN32) || defined(_WIN32) || defined(__SYMBIAN32__)
#  if defined(BUILDING_LIBCURL)
#    define CURL_EXTERN  __declspec(dllexport)
#  else
#    define CURL_EXTERN  __declspec(dllimport)
#  endif
#elif defined(BUILDING_LIBCURL) && defined(CURL_HIDDEN_SYMBOLS)
#  define CURL_EXTERN CURL_EXTERN_SYMBOL
#else
#  define CURL_EXTERN
#endif
```

Therefore if you are linking against a static version of curl ,  you have to define CURL_STATICLIB before the `#include <curl/curl.h>`