# trying to include curl library, Get the following error from nmake: windows.h file not found

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, curl, libcurl

My System information : Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard, 64 bit

---

I am trying to use Curl(http://curl.haxx.se/) Library with my c++ code(Visual Studio MFC). I'm trying to build libcurl.dll from the curl source using nmake (Visual Studio 10). I need to run the following command from Visual Studio Command Prompt:

```
nmake /f Makefile.vc mode=dll
```

I get the following error:[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BHj3.png)

Comment: Have you already tried `build.bat` instead of `nmake` ? https://github.com/blackrosezy/build-libcurl-windows

Comment: Just tried it, The build.bat does not output anything. build.bat file opens and closes right away, doesn't seem like it did anything.

Comment: Have you carefully follwed the steps of installation described here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/install.html

Comment: P.S.: Read the "MSVC from command line" or "MSVC IDE" section depending on your preference (commande line or IDE)

Comment: I was successfully able to produce the libcurl.dll with the "MSVC IDE" method without any errors. I included this libcurl.dll with my project but when I try to #include <curl/curl.h>, it cannot be found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to mikedu95, I was able to solve this.

Follow instruction from  curl.haxx.se/docs/install.html ("MSVC IDE" in my case)

Then Follow:[Getting LibCurl to work with Visual Studio 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20171165/getting-libcurl-to-work-with-visual-studio-2013)

This will setup everything you need