# MVS Community and cURL c++

Tags: c++, windows, curl, nmake

*BUMP*

Good afternoon,

I've been browsing google looking for a comprehensible guide to installing and adding the dependencies of cURL for Visual Studio Community with no real progress.

I've downloaded and extracted the package to C:\curl\curl-7.47.1 and built it by using the Developer Command Prompt from the winbuild\ (nmake /f Makefile.vc mode=dll).

The problems start as I try to find the libraries and includes that I am supposed to add to MVS' dependencies. 
The three builds are built with no issues and added to the root of the cURL directory, but there is no release\ or debug\ in the package that I can add to my dependencies (the lib\ only has two libcurl files in it).

I've attempted to use a trial/error approach to finding the correct dependencies in a test project, but can't seem to get rid of the errors (ie. not having the correct dependencies).

I'm not sure if this has to do with the fact that I am using VS community, or if I simply am making some sort of errors in the "installation" process, and since none of the guides that I have found seem to help me I thought I'd turn to you guys.

cURL seems to be a somewhat commonly used library (if not the best URL-library?) and should see quite frequent use, but I can't for the love of me find a solution to the above mentioned problem(s).

Thank you for your help and please do tell me if you need any further information!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved by looking into the (un)marked answer of one of many questions of SO.

Look at mtlynch's answer at: 
[Getting LibCurl to work with Visual Studio 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20171165/getting-libcurl-to-work-with-visual-studio-2013)