# How to debug an SSL connect error using libcurl in C++ (vs2013)

Tags: c++11, curl, visual-studio-2013

I recently went about compiling libcurl for use with Vs2013, which turned out to fairly straight forward thanks to some [very useful help here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20171165/getting-libcurl-to-work-with-visual-studio-2013). After some cajoling and more online help, I've even managed to get curl to play nice inside a unique_ptr.

Standard HTTP and HTTPS transactions using curl work fine with `google.com`. However, a particular site using https (www.slayradio.org) unfortunately results in an 'SSL connect error'.

I have no problem connecting to the domain via https using curl in PHP. But I need it to work in C++ as well.

It seems that [CURLOPT_VERBOSE](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_VERBOSE.html) is just the ticket, but turning it on seems to have no effect what so ever. I see no additional output in either the console window, nor the internal IDE output window. I messed around with the [CURLOPT_STDERR option](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_STDERR.html) trying to specific a concrete file it should output to for a while, until I finally discovered that via the [curl FAQ](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/faq.html#Does_CURLOPT_WRITEDATA_and_CURLO) that passing a FILE* pointer to the libcurl DLL (which I do) causes an access violation. I know the FAQ specifically refers to CURLOPT_WRITEDATA and CURLOPT_READDATA, **not** CURLOPT_STDERR, but I can't imagine the same isn't the case, here.

I've discovered the [CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER.html) setting, which a yields a slightly more helpful output:

```
Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to www.slayradio.org:443
```

But I'm still at a loss at what's causing issues.

It'd much appreciate if anyone can tell me if I shouldn't actually be seeing more output by enabling CURLOPT_VERBOSE in the console window?

I'd also be curious to hear if someone can has run into something similar before.

If I can't get Curl to be more verbose, it seems like the only option is to make use of the [CURLOPT_DEBUGFUNCTION](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_DEBUGFUNCTION.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this is only a half-answer.

First and foremost I did not, and have still not, gotten to the bottom of why turning on CURLOPT_VERBOSE seemingly does nothing. Setting CURLOPT_VERBOSE to 1L seems to change nothing.

However, I did manage to find the root of the problems I was experiencing. I isolated the newly compiled cUrl library to a new project, and realized that a different/older cUrl library from TwitCurl was still hanging around on my system along with some libraries for the SSL/TLS protocol. This ended up interfering with the newly compiled cUrl library, causing it to not be able to figure out which protocols were available to it.

So... I guess the best advice I can give is to further isolate the problem if possible (which I should have done from the start), and be wary of older libraries hanging about.