# How to setup libcurl on visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, libcurl

I am using windows 10, and using Visual Studio 2013 (because I have some library dependencies). I want to use libcurl to make HTTP request to my local server. So I download library from [here](https://curl.haxx.se/download.html) which is version 7.6.0.

I downloaded and install MinGW and CMake and followed [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/windows/195514/) instruction. After that I am completely lost on how to Add this library to my project.

So I added

```
"..\curl-7.60.0\include"
"..\curlpp-0.8.1\include"
```

to my project's C/C++ > `Additional Include Directories` and I also added

```
"..\curl-7.60.0\build\lib\libcurl_imp.lib"
"..\curl-7.60.0\lib"
"..\curl-7.60.0\build\lib\libcurl.dll"
"..\curl-7.60.0\build\lib"
"..\curl-7.60.0\build\src"
"..\curlpp-0.8.1\build\CMakeFiles\curlpp_static.dir\src"
```

to my project's Linkers > `Additional Directories Libraries`

But when I added these code to my project and run it. I've got a linker error. Please help, I have no idea how to add the dependencies :-P

code:

```
#include <curl/curl.h>
...
void AppMain::setup() {
    ...
    long flags = CURL_GLOBAL_ALL;
    CURLcode curlcode = curl_global_init(flags ); 
    return 0;
}
```

error:

```
Error 5 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _curl_global_init referenced in function "public: void __thiscall AppMain::setup(void)" (?setup@AppMain@@QAEXXZ)
```

Comment: You have added the libraries to link with in the *directories* to search for libraries. You must tell MSVC to *link* with the libraries instead.

Comment: Could you provide some guide line? Because right now I have no idea how to link the libraries.

Comment: I tried adding `libcurl_imp.lib` to Linker > Input > `Additional Dependencies` but still got the same error :-\

Comment: I followed instruction from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20171165/getting-libcurl-to-work-with-visual-studio-2013) post from user mtlynch (second answer), and now instead of just 1 linker error, I've got like 63 errors of linker errors. There are now 2 types of errors, first unresolved external symbol, and `error LNK2005: _strtoll already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(strtoq.obj)`.

:-P

Answer (score 1):

Install vcpkg ( MS packager to install windows based open source projects) and use powershell command like so `.\vcpkg install libcurl:x64-windows-static`. Dependency libraries will be auto installed for you. The libcurl library can be auto integrated to your VS project using `.\vcpkg integrate install`.

Comment: In prerequisite it said `Visual Studio 2017 or Visual Studio 2015 Update 3`. Is it possible to install VS 2017 and use vcpkg on VS 2013?

Comment: @HarveyCordeiro: No, Use VS2017. THe compiler will also be used during cross compiling.